# Creating an animation using 2 images

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I already have this coded and working, however I am just wondering if there is a better solution for this.

Here is my code which currently does work:

```
    _index = 1;
    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.schedule(new TickClass(), 1000, 1000);

public class TickClass extends TimerTask
{
    private int columnIndex;

    @Override
    public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (_index == 1) {
                        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IMAGE_2);
                        _index = 2;
                    }
                    else {
                        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_IMAGE_1);
                        _index = 1; 
                    }   

                    String image_1 = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    image_1 = image_1.replace(".png", "");
                    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(getPackageName() + ":drawable/" + image_1, null, null);
                    image_1_view.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resourceId));
                }
            });
        }
}
```

As you can see the 2 drawable names come from an SQLite database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AnimationDrawable is an "official" way of creating animations from multiple images

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Comment: Yes thats great but if you look at the code the drawables are being animated on the fly with strings (for the filenames) that are taken from the database.

Comment: Yes but the strings from the database point to a drawable resource.  You can take those strings from the database and configure AnimationDrawable on the fly by calling AnimationDrawable.addFrame()

Comment: Not at all, glad it was helpful!